# Error of To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"

Tags: model-view-controller, membership-provider

I want to use membership provider in empty project but i am facing problem at logout time
Any suggestion plz??

Comment: Pls try to add Membership dll in your project. If added already then include it on you page/class.

Comment: @AK47 still having same error at logout time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by just adding Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers into my project by nuget